# Creating response to answering quiz questions in a table

Tags: ios, ipad

I am creating an app for medical students, and one view is a quiz mode that randomly generates quiz questions with a table view of the answer options. In the current stage, the user selects an answer from the table view, and a text field below the table view tells them whether they are right or not. 
What I would like to do is, when the user clicks an answer, if the answer is correct, the selected answer in the table is highlighted green. If the answer is wrong, the selected answer would turn red, and the correct answer in the table would turn red. Anyone know if it's possible to have different selection background colors in the same table (and also whether the logic described is possible)?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, beware it is not tested:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row != self.correctAnswerRow)
    {
        UITableViewCell *wrongCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [wrongCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }

    UITableViewCell *correctCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.correctAnswerRow inSection:indexPath.section]];
    [correctCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```